# Wordpress automatically zooms images on upload

Tags: wordpress, image

I got this very weird problem: When I upload a image, sometimes Wordpress zooms it in automatically. However: the dimensions remain the same. So let's say I upload an image of 244x501 pixels, it stays 244x501 pixels according to Wordpress, but it is CLEARLY zoomed in bigger than original (by about +25%), and therefore blurry. It doesn't always happen, just sometimes. I'm NOT trying to upload extremely big or small images or something. I also tried to turn off all my plugins and switching theme's, but didn't work. I tried saving as different format (jpg, png etc.), also didn't work. The problem ain't Photoshop or the windows photo viewer either. The problem has to be with the Wordpress library/uploader... It looks like it does upload the original size, but then shows it zoomed in on both the library and in the actual post. So it says for example 244x501, while in reality it's something like 302x627 or so... Anyone can help me? It's so frustrating...

Comment: Without seeing your code and setup, its impossible for us to know what your WP is doing! Are you sure the problem is with the images themselves, and not that the code is displaying a larger version if the uploaded image in the template files, or smaller image that it is stretching? But we are not mind readers so we really have no idea based on what you have told us and can only guess at what *might* be happening.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a problem with the WordPress media library, or is there a problem with the site as well?
For example, you upload an image and it is correct in the library at the counter but it is zoomed in or displayed incorrectly on the site?
If this happens, use this function to call the post image:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
```

Also check what dimensions WordPress displays?
You can check this in the index.php and single.php files.

for example

```
//Default WordPress
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );     // Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );        // Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large' );  // Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );         // Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );          // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
 
//With WooCommerce
the_post_thumbnail( 'shop_thumbnail' ); // Shop thumbnail (180 x 180 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'shop_catalog' );   // Shop catalog (300 x 300 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'shop_single' );    // Shop single (600 x 600 hard cropped)
```